# Rigid space, but with homeomorphic neighborhoods

Tags: gn.general-topology

What is an example of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ on more than one point, with the following properties?

1. the only homeomorphism from $X$ to itself is the identity, and
2. given $x,y\in X$ there are open sets $U, V$ with $x\in U, y\in V$ and a homeomorphism $\varphi: U\to V$ such that $\varphi(x) = y$, where $U,V$ are endowed with their respective subspace topologies.

Comment: Do you want the homeomoprhism from U to V to send x to y in the second condition? As stated, it looks like you can always choose $U=V=X$.

Comment: Thanks for asking this - I will correct the post!

Comment: Don't you want a Hausdorff space?

Comment: @YCor there are Hausdorff (even metrizable) examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $U_n=\{m\in\mathbb N:m\geq n\}$. Then $\tau=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{U_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb N$. This space is rigid because $n$ is characterized as the unique element contained in exactly $n+1$ open sets. However, for any $n,m$ the sets $U_n,U_m$ are homeomorphic through a map $k\mapsto k-n+m$ which takes $n$ to $m$.

Answer (score 8):

There exists a metrizable topological group $H$ such that $H \setminus \{e\}$ is rigid (see Theorem 6.1 in van Mill´s paper: [A topological group having no homeomorphisms other than translations](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1983-280-02/S0002-9947-1983-0716833-2/S0002-9947-1983-0716833-2.pdf)).

**Exercise:** Without knowing anything else about $H$, show that $X=H \setminus\{e\}$ satisfies condition 2 in the OP.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually a locally connected and connected topological group $H$, which has exponent 2.

Comment: @ramirodelavega This exercise kept me busy during a long (and boring) business meeting - thanks! (PS, haven't quite cracked it yet.)